# SOAP Web Service error : unexpected element name: expected=expectedName, actual: {http://services/}expectedName

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl

I need your help please. I have created a simple soap web service that I have deployed on tomcat. the code is that one below

```
package services;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebResult;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;

@SOAPBinding(style=Style.RPC)
@WebService(wsdlLocation="http://localhost:8080/WS/soap")
public interface servicesInterface {

@WebResult(partName="name")
String createOperation( @WebParam(partName="name",   targetNamespace="/http://services/") String name);
}
```

And its implementation class

```
package services;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import list.names;

@WebService(endpointInterface="services.servicesInterface")
public class servicesImpl implements servicesInterface{

public String createOperation(String name) {
    System.out.println("CREATE " + name + "\n");
    return name;
}}
```

Then the Generated WSDL is the follow

```
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://services/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" targetNamespace="http://services/" name="servicesImplService">
<types/>
<message name="createOperation">
<part name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="createOperationResponse">
<part name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<portType name="servicesInterface">
<operation name="createOperation" parameterOrder="name">
<input message="tns:createOperation"/>
<output message="tns:createOperationResponse"/>
</operation>
</portType>
<binding name="servicesImplPortBinding" type="tns:servicesInterface">
<soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<operation name="createOperation">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://services/"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://services/"/>
</output>
</operation>
</binding>
<service name="servicesImplService">
<port name="servicesImplPort" binding="tns:servicesImplPortBinding">
<soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/WS/soap"/>
</port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

now, using Wizdler from my browser to test it, I have the following request

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Body>
        <createOperation xmlns="http://services/">
            <name>JonDoe</name>
        </createOperation>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

and I get this ERROR: That I have tried to fix for 2 days.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <soapenv:Fault xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
            <faultstring>unexpected element name: expected=name, actual: {http://services/}name</faultstring>
        </soapenv:Fault>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Thank you in advance.

PS: By the way, when I try to change the soapBinding style into Document "@SOAPBinding(style=Style.DOCUMENT)", I get also this error:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
GRAVE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of    class com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener
WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: class:   services.jaxws.CreateOperation could not be found
at  com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.contextInitialized(WSServletContextListener.java:130)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4812)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3828)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.backgroundProcess(StandardContext.java:5616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1377)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1381)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1381)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1349)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: class: services.jaxws.CreateOperation could not be found
at com.sun.xml.ws.modeler.RuntimeModeler.getClass(RuntimeModeler.java:269)
at com.sun.xml.ws.modeler.RuntimeModeler.processDocWrappedMethod(RuntimeModeler.java:558)
at com.sun.xml.ws.modeler.RuntimeModeler.processMethod(RuntimeModeler.java:505)
at com.sun.xml.ws.modeler.RuntimeModeler.processClass(RuntimeModeler.java:353)
at com.sun.xml.ws.modeler.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(RuntimeModeler.java:249)
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.RuntimeEndpointInfo.createModel(RuntimeEndpointInfo.java:180)
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.RuntimeEndpointInfo.init(RuntimeEndpointInfo.java:326)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.createModelAndMetadata(WSServletContextListener.java:203)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.contextInitialized(WSServletContextListener.java:119)
... 11 more
```

Can you Tell me why it happens and what it means please? Thanx again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Author of Wizdler here. The wizdler generated the `name` element in the `http://services/` namespace and it should be in the default namespace (the empty namespace). This is also what the error message is trying to say: `unexpected element name: expected=name, actual: {http://services/}name`.

To fix this, set the namespace of the `name` element to an empty string:

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Body>
        <createOperation xmlns="http://services/">
            <name xmlns="">JonDoe</name>
        </createOperation>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

If this helps, you can add new issue here: https://github.com/pepri/wizdler/issues

Comment: it works. Thank you. but one thing: this solution can takes too long when I have an objet with a lot of attributes. what should I use in the java web class to do it automatically. I have tried the (@WebParam(partName="name",targetNamespace="") but the xml in wizdler doesn't change. Thanks again